# Valid to run glmnet package with single lambda value for lasso regression instead of sequence of lambda values?

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

I'm executing a few test runs of a lasso regression with the glmnet package in R using the diabetes dataset (http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.tab.txt). I’m choosing a single lambda value = 0.1 (not a sequence of lambda values) and alpha=1:

```
> set.seed(1);
  elasticnet_fit <- glmnet(data_matrix, y, family="gaussian", lambda=.1, alpha=1); 
  coef(elasticnet_fit);
11 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       s0
(Intercept) -299.82915923
x1            -0.02102016
x2             5.63508548
x3             1.10288671
x4            -0.73514322
x5             0.42465094
x6            -0.03356997
x7             5.39641052
x8            59.76829212
x9             0.27508521
x10          -22.34877815
```

I noticed the glmnet documentation reads as follows when selecting lambda values:

> WARNING: use with care. Do not supply a single value for lambda (for
>   predictions after CV use predict() instead). Supply instead a
>   decreasing sequence of lambda values. glmnet relies on its warms
>   starts for speed, and its often faster to fit a whole path than
>   compute a single fit.

Are the coefficient estimates invalid when supplying only a single lambda value rather than a sequence? (Cross-posting from Stack Overflow.)

Comment: In my experience, providing a single value of `lambda` is prone to causing errors. In any case, the authors' note about warm starts improving computation speed makes one wonder why you'd ever elect *not* to compute the entire solution.

Comment: @user777 - Is there a glitch in the glmnet algorithm that causes errors when running glmnet on a single lambda value? I'm developing my own coordinate descent code in another language (SAS) and wanted to make sure my coefficient estimates for a single lambda matched results for the same lasso regression in glmnet before expanding my code to a CV solution from a sequence of lambdas.

Comment: I can only speculate as to the cause of the error. To your point, as the authors note, you can still access the coefficients for a single lambda value by using `predict`.

Comment: @user777 - Yes, I think this is what I want: predict(elasticnet_fit,type="coefficient",s=.1), thanks.

Comment: For safety, I would try `predict(elasticnet_fit,type="coefficient",s=.1, exact=T)` since the (faster) default is exact=F, which is interpolation between the two adjacent lambda values.

Comment: @user777 - Hmm, the predict() function returns the same coefficient estimates as the glmnet() function, which according to the documentation should be used with care. Maybe I got the correct(?) values all along, although they differ from the results in my own coordinate descent code.